# Is this group a Kahler group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $S$ be a non-orientable closed surface with $b_{1}(S)=2$, is $\pi_{1}(S)$ a Kahler group?

Comment: Take a 2-fold non-orientable covering $S'\to S$. Then $\chi(S')=2\chi(S)=-2$, hence, $b_1(S')=3$, odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3033516

It follows from the Biswas-Mj result that a one-relator Kahler group has no torsion in $G^{ab}$. But your group is a one-relator group with torsion in $G^{ab}$.